# How to daisy chain 2 Thunderbolt devices on 1 Thunderbolt port?

Tags: external-disk, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display, daisy-chaining

On an iMac with 1 Thunderbolt port, how to have an external monitor and an external HDD work?

I can't use the USB port because it's 2.0, it will be too slow (the external HDD is a SSD).

I understand the display needs to go last, because it's actually mini-displayport. But what about the HDD? I can't find a single external HDD that has 2 Thunderbolt ports (one IN, one OUT).

So how are you supposed to daisy chain things?

Comment: Also the search for drives to support chaining is already asked as well. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43827/what-thunderbolt-hard-drives-support-daisychaining

Comment: @bmike The question was asked 3 years ago when Thunderbolt appeared. The answers are like `From what I've read, the initial devices will be…`, or `I think we'll see…`. Nothing useful for today.

Comment: The ideal solution is to fix the older question, down vote and comment on the bad answers. You could also edit your question to explain specifically how the linked question doesn't solve your problem. When it's not a duplicate question, it will get reopened rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

The Belkin Silver F4U055WW Thunderbolt Express Dock has only 2 Thunderbolt ports. Your answer does not address the problem. I have an OWC dock that is similar, 2 Thunderbolt ports. On both docks, one of the 2 ports is used to connect to the computer - leaving you with 1!

I don't get it. Just have to wait for hardware developers I suppose...

- alphajolt

You can use an external Thunderbolt express dock. I use a thunderbolt dock for daisy chaining. It allows me to connect up to 5 thunderbolt devices.

It offers the following benefits:

- One cable provides access to 8 ports
- Daisy-chain up to 5 Thunderbolt devices
- Cable-management channel

It's compatible with the following devices:

- MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, Mac Mini, and iMac

This is what I use for daisy chaining my thunderbolt devices.

Here's a link to New Egg so you can see the full details of the device and reviews:

[Belkin Thunderbolt Thunderbolt Express Dock (NewEgg)](http://www.neweggbusiness.com/Product/Product.aspx?gclid=CNrOu77gs78CFWMQ7AodeQgARA&Item=9B-15-108-024&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleBiz&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleBiz-_-pla-_-Docking%20Station-_-9B-15-108-024&ef_id=U3YiKQAAAbIGqzsQ:20140707174444:s)

Comment: Wow, yes it would work but it costs more than 120 € and it weights more than 1 kilogram, that's not really the simplest solution. I hope that's not the only one I have :/

Comment: When I was looking for a daisy chain solution, I couldn't find anything cheaper, after all, it's for an Apple device. Nothing Apple related comes cheap. Apple sells an Apple endorsed thunderbolt hub/device on their site but it costs over $800.00 US. I figured $160.00 US was a bargain.

Comment: Yes but I don't want an additional device/hub, Thunderbolt was supposed to be about daisy chaining devices (i.e. no need for a dock). I've seen reviews where people chain up like 10 HDD on a single Thunderbolt port. I wonder how they do that: how is Thunderbolt's chaining supposed to be used?

Comment: The thunderbolt daisy chain process without a hub would still require the device (the one that will be daisy chained) to have a thunderbolt in/out connection.